Can photos of misspelled public business signs (or links to Google Street View) be used to advertise a spelling consultancy?
If a business has a sign above their door or elsewhere displayed along a public road such that it is prominently displayed to passing car and pedestrian traffic, what would the main legal issues be if one took personal photos of those signs and used them to electronically advertise their quick-turnaround time, mobile spelling consultancy.
What about embedded Google Street View links in the advertisements instead of personal photos?
Background: While most sign makers would likely instantly flag a misspelling in a customer's request before making the sign if it's in their native (or the local) language, if the sign includes a second language they may not catch that, and assume the customer has done their "due dilligence". And in some cases signs are made by the proprietors themselves (i.e. DIY signs).

Extreme example, source: Google Street View


While this would have to be evaluated on a case by case basis, there is a good argument that this would not give rise to either trademark or copyright infringement liability, and those are the only two kinds of intellectual property likely to be relevant.
A business sign is often so short that it won't even be significant enough to be eligible for copyright protection at all, and often it isn't in the nature of a trademark that has a secondary meaning associated with the business.
Even when it does have copyright protection or trademark protection, in the case of a copyright there is a good argument for fair use in the his context, and in the context of trademark protection, there is a good argument that use in this way amounts to protected nominative use.
From the copyright fair use prospective, the goal isn't to appropriate the intended literary value of the sign, but to engage in social commentary, even if it is presented in a for profit context. Also, in the worst case scenario, any damages award is likely to be modest because the case that there are lost revenues to the copyright owner is dubious and this isn't the kind of fact pattern where judges impose high statutory damages.
From the nominative use perspective, the goal isn't to intimate a connection or endorsement to the trademark owner, and a misspelled sign is almost never going to be a "famous" mark or present concerns about trademark dilution.
Because it is a case by case analysis, the risk is never zero. But with these facts there is a pretty low risk of intellectual property infringement liability.
Also, of course, there is almost no risk of defamation liability, assuming of course, that the reputation harming images of spelling errors are authentic pictures and not doctored in some way by the business using them to make them look bad when the really sign actually isn't misspelled, for example.

scrolling YouTube shorts during morning coffee I came across this very nice implementation of something similar https://www.youtube.com/shorts/Iui5jj8zhv8?feature=share  Her message: "Hire a professional, people."
